# Copying and renaming files from different folders and same folder based on path from the configuration SQL table

Tags: csv, foreach, azure-data-factory, file-rename, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a adls folder outbound which has sub folders in it and my partition CSV file is present in multiple sub folders of outbound folder.

PFA picture [config_table_folder_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTPaT.jpg) for the folder paths of my files which I'm fetching from my configuration table

1st pipeline : copies data from SQL tables to respective adls folders provided in the configuration table

These files are partition files which has to be renamed.

2nd pipeline : copies files from respective folder paths renames them and copies to the same folder path again and deletes the older files.

PFA picture of 2nd pipeline
[Main pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvPYG.jpg)
[Execute pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0x8E.jpg)

1. Lookup = to fetch the folder path from my configuration SQL table
2. Foreach = to loop through each path as there are multiple folder paths as you can see in the above config table picture

> In order to loop through each file I have a execute pipeline

3. Execute pipeline = has a parameter folderpath = item().DEST_FOLDER_PATH

3.1 Get metadata = to get all the files inside the folder

3.2. Foreach = to loop through each file

3.3 Copy activity = to rename each file present in the folders

3.4 Delete = since the copy activity creates a new file after renaming, to delete the older files

Csvdataset][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRRAu.jpg)

Expected output of CSV file names after removing the underscore and adding the digits after underscore with hhmmss of my filename

MAIN ISSUE

The above approach works only when each file is in a different folder, but it throws error when there are multiple files in same folder
I do not have any issue with the expected output, my issue is that my pipeline fails when the folder path is same for all files and throws an error while it iterates 2nd time which is not required
for example if my folder is  outbound/NL/historical and i have 5 files in this historical folder ,the foreach is running 5 times which i do not want as after the 1st loop itself my files would be renamed , it's executing 5 times and throwing error

I have tried not using getmetada but I need the getmetada to iterate through multiple files from same folders.

I have tried not using getmetada but I need the getmetada to iterate through multiple files from same folder .

I want my pipeline to work even if the multiple files are present in same folder and even when multiple files are present in multiple folders
[Copy source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W696b.jpg)
[Copy sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78IBr.jpg) [delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJDB.jpg) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N6U5.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the copy activity and delete activity confgurations inside the child pipeline? also the error message for better understanding?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I've attached the pictures of copy source, sink, delete activity and error message. I ran my pipeline providing the same folder path for all the files and instead of iterating only once and renaming, it's trying to iterate more 5 times as I have 5 files, and it's throwing the above error for the 2nd iteration, the reason why I want to iterate for folder path is because I have a scenario where the files are present in different folders, I get the above error when more than 1 file is present in a folder

Comment: The error suggests that there is something wrong with `substring` function. what is the expression for the filepath of the sink?

Comment: Yes the error is coming because it is trying to rename the files which are already renamed in the first iteration. I'm passing the output of my lookup which fetches the folder path from 1st pipeline as a pipeline parameter to the execute pipeline so that is the path in sink

Comment: why are you renaming all the files at once and why not just rename them one by one and delete it in every iteration? because you can't exit from for-loop till the iterations get completed.

Comment: Okay let me try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps in the child pipeline to achieve your requirement.

In the child pipeline Get meta data activity, take another dataset with parameters till only the folder path. Provide the `folderpath` pipeline parameter to it so that in every child pipeline run, the folder path changes as per the parent pipeline iteration.

[image]

Give the Child items array to the for-loop. In the **copy activity source** inside for-loop, you are using wild card file path `*.csv` which copies all files ends with `.csv` to the target(renamed file).

It means, For example, if the source folder files are in order `file1.csv`,`file2.csv`, it will take all `csv` files and copies one by one into the same target location in one iteration. It results, the generated target file(renamed file)'s content after each iteration is only `file2.csv`'s content because it overwrites the last source file content into the target file.

So, you should not use wild card file path like above. **Just use dataset parameters for container, folder path and filepath**. Provide the necessary values for those in the copy activity source like below. Give the current file `@item().name` for the file path.

[image]

In the sink also do the same, but **give your file rename expression** for the `filepath`. Here, for sample, I have given `@replace(item().name,'_','')` to rename the files.

[image]

Next, to delete the current file, give the same values like copy activity source in the delete activity as well.

[image]

After creating new file in every iteration, this will delete the old file.

Now, Debug the parent pipeline and it will give expected results.

**My source files before pipeline run:**

[image]

**New files after pipeline run:**

[image]

If your pipeline is slow, you can uncheck the sequential check box in the for-loops, so that the iterations complete in parallel.